# Automake config cannot compile my unit test

Tags: autotools, glib, automake, gobject

I'm new to C and Automake development. So this could be a stupid question.

I'm recently working on a C library that links to GLib and GObject. I've got my Makefile.am and configure.ac working through the compilation. However, when I tried to compile the unit test, a series of error occurs. The errors are similar to this:

```
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_intern_static_string'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_once_init_enter'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_free'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_once_init_leave'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_name'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_value_set_string'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_class_adjust_private_offset'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_return_if_fail_warning'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_object_new'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_class_peek_parent'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_param_spec_string'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_check_class_cast'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_class_add_private'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_register_static_simple'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_log'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_value_dup_string'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_type_instance_get_private'
src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_object_class_install_properties'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where should I **start looking** to solve this?

## Further information of my project:

### Directory structure

---

- /

  - src/

    - foobar-hello.c
    - foobar-hello.h
  - tests/

    - test-foobar-hello.c
  - Makefile.am
  - configure.ac
  - autogen.sh
  - README.md

---

### Autotools related files

**Makefile.am**

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS  = -I m4 ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects

# -- Common build flags --------------
AM_CFLAGS = $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/src


# -- Library -------------------------
lib_LTLIBRARIES = src/libfoobar.la

src_libfoobar_la_SOURCES = \
        src/foobar-hello.c \
        $(NULL)

src_libfoobar_la_include_HEADERS = \
        src/foobar-hello.h \
        $(NULL)

src_libfoobar_la_includedir = $(includedir)/foobar


# -- Tests ---------------------------
check_PROGRAMS = \
        tests/test_foobar_hello \
        $(NULL)

tests_test_foobar_hello_SOURCES = tests/test-foobar-hello.c
tests_test_foobar_hello_LDADD = src/libfoobar.la

TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS)


# -- Common --------------------------
CLEANFILES = \
        $(NULL)

EXTRA_DIST = \
        autogen.sh \
        README.md \
        $(NULL)
```

**configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ(2.63)
AC_INIT([libfoobar], [0.1], [https://github.com/foobar/libfoobar/issues], [libfoobar], [https://github.com/foobar/libfoobar])

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11 no-dist-gzip dist-xz tar-ustar foreign])
AC_PROG_MKDIR_P

m4_ifdef([AM_SILENT_RULES],[AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])])

# Check library versions
# then substitute the revelant cflag with actual library information
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GLIB],[glib-2.0 > 2.19.0])
AC_SUBST(GLIB_CFLAGS)

# Initialize libtool
LT_INIT([disable-static])

# OUTPUT files
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
  Makefile
])


AC_OUTPUT
```

---

Edited:

## Solution

After reading [ldavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425738/ldav1s)'s helpful answer, here is what I done:

1. I've added these 2 lines in `configure.ac`:

   ```
   PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GOBJECT],[gobject-2.0])
   AC_SUBST(GOBJECT_CFLAGS)
   ```
2. I changed the `AM_CFLAGS` line in `Makefile.am`:

   ```
   AM_CFLAGS = $(GLIB_CFLAGS) $(GOBJECT_CFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/src
   ```
3. I added this line to `Makefile.am`:

   ```
   src_libfoobar_la_LIBADD = $(GLIB_LIBS) $(GOBJECT_LIBS)
   ```

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by looking at the error carefully:

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This tells you it's a linker error (`ld` is the linker).

> src/.libs/libfoobar.so: undefined reference to `g_intern_static_string'

The linker cannot find a symbol in `src/.libs/libfoobar.so` (a shared library) which you are linking to your test program.  So `src/.libs/libfoobar.so` is probably missing at least one dependent library, but probably two dependent libraries (the aformentioned `libglib` and `libgobject`).  They need to be linked to `libfoobar.so`.

Modern versions of the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro are *supposed* to `AC_SUBST` *foo*`_LIBS` and *foo*`_CFLAGS` variables, (e.g. `GLIB_LIBS` and `GLIB_CFLAGS`).  This needs to be added to the Makefile to link `libglib`:

**Makefile.am**

```
src_libfoobar_la_LDADD = $(GLIB_LIBS)
```

This still won't link your test code, but you should have fewer errors.  You'll need to `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` for `libgobject` in `configure.ac`, and plug in the corresponding `GOBJECT_CFLAGS` and `GOBJECT_LIBS` in the right places in `Makefile.am`.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment is really helpful. I've added the `GOBJECT` parameters with appropriate `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` and `AC_SUBST` in `configure.ac`. Then I added `src_libfoobar_la_LIBADD = $(GLIB_LIBS) $(GOBJECT_LIBS)` line to `Makefile.am`. I also added `$(OBJECT_CFLAGS)` to `AM_CFLAGS`. It works like a charm.